# What exactly onCreate() method will do in a Fragment Life Cycle in an Android Application

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-lifecycle, fragment-lifecycle

I am confusing onCreate() method in both Activity and Fragment. What onCreate() will do in Fragment and What are differences onCreate() method between Activity and Fragment.Please help me i am learning by myself.

Thanks......

Answer (score 0):

**onCreate()**

The system calls this when creating the fragment. Within your implementation, you should initialize essential components of the fragment that you want to retain when the fragment is paused or stopped, then resumed.